# i need to find 5 dates in which the greatest number of orders were placed from excel file

Tags: python, excel

[here is the example of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1e2T.png)

```
 import pandas as pd
 # read excel file
 df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/samer/Desktop/project/online_retail2.xlsx")
 df.head()
 # is gonna remove nan from the equation
 df = df.dropna()

 columns = list(df.columns)
 columns = [x.lower() for x in columns]
 df.columns = columns
 #task 2.1
 df['stockcode'] = df['stockcode'].apply(str)

 df["products ordered by individuals"] = df["description"] + [' '] + df["stockcode"]

 top_products = df['products ordered by individuals'].value_counts()[:10]
 print('Top 10 products ordered by individuals:\n' , top_products)

 #task 2.2
 df['sales'] = df['price'] * df['quantity']
 The_most_money_spent= df.groupby("customer id").sum().sort_values("sales", ascending=False).head(10)
 print("Top ten customers who spent most money are: \n" ,The_most_money_spent)


#task 2.3
top_orders_were_placed = df[['invoicedate','sales']].value_counts('sales','invoicedate', 
ascending=False)
top_orders_were_placed.head(5)


df['orders']= df[['sales', 'invoicedate']]
top_orders_were_placed= df['orders'].value_counts(ascending=False)
top_orders_were_placed.head()
```

I'm trying to find a way to get the greatest number of products, but I just don't know how to use or find the date from the file. despite numerous attempts, I just can't figure it out, and it's been 2 days, so what exactly should I use?

Comment: You must create a new column keeping only the date from your date column (remove the time) and then group by and aggregate by count

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: df['invoicedate']= pd.to_datetime(df['invoicedate'])
    date = df["invoicedate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["invoicedate"]).dt.date
    df["invoicedate"] = date
    greatest_five_dates = df.groupby("invoicedate").count().sort_values("invoice", 
     ascending=False).head(5)
     print("the greatest five dates are sorted by the invoicedate 
     raw:\n",greatest_five_dates, "\n")                                                                                          i tried this code i got smt but im not sure of it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use groupby function of pandas. You need to groupby by date and then summarize the quantity. After that you just need to sort values by descending.